# Trying to get unique field values of four columns with other columns in query

Tags: sql-server

I have this table that has 30 columns in it.  A partial group of those columns are going to be selected out of the table, into a reference table.  The columns are as follows:

```
Agent_SK  <-- Hash of Agent's Name, Phone, Address, and Email.
, Agent_License_Number  <-- Nullable data field...NOT PK or UNIQUE
, Agent_Name
, Agent_Phone
, Agent_Address
, Agent_Email
, Office_Name
, Office_Phone
, Office_Address
, Office_Email
, Last_Update_Date
```

*Of note, Agent_SK is null if all of the 4 fields are NULL.*

What I need, is unique combination of `Agent_Name, Phone, Address, and Email`, with the rest of the columns brought on based on latest update of the 4-column combination.

I've tried multiple tries of:

```
Insert into property.dbo.MLSRealtor
select
    M1.Agent_SK
    , M2.Listing_Agent_License_Number
    , M2.Listing_Agent_Name
    , M2.Listing_Agent_Address
    , M2.Listing_Agent_Phone
    , M2.Listing_Agent_Email
    , M2.Office_Name
    , M2.Office_Address
    , M2.Office_Phone
    , M2.Office_Email
    , M2.Update_Timestamp
from 
(
select distinct Agent_SK
from MLS
where Agent_SK is not null
) M1
left join
(
    select
        Agent_SK
        , Listing_Agent_License_Number
        , Listing_Agent_Name
        , Listing_Agent_Address
        , Listing_Agent_Phone
        , Listing_Agent_Email
        , Office_Name
        , Office_Address
        , Office_Phone
        , Office_Email
        , Max(Update_Timestamp) as Update_Timestamp
    from MLS M
    group by Agent_SK
        , Listing_Agent_License_Number
        , Listing_Agent_Name
        , Listing_Agent_Address
        , Listing_Agent_Phone
        , Listing_Agent_Email
        , Office_Name
        , Office_Address
        , Office_Phone
        , Office_Email
) M2
on M1.Agent_SK = M2.Agent_SK;
```

It appears I'm accidentally grouping Office information with teh Listing information, leading to duplicate Agent_SK.

I need whatever Office info is there for the latest record of that Agent_SK.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to extract the latest-per-group record:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent_Name, Agent_Phone, Agent_Address, Agent_Email
                   ORDER BY Last_Update_Date DESC) AS rn
```

You can filter, based on the above calculated field, with `rn = 1`.

So, your `INSERT` will look like this:

```
Insert into property.dbo.MLSRealtor
select
    Agent_SK
    , Listing_Agent_License_Number
    , Listing_Agent_Name
    , Listing_Agent_Address
    , Listing_Agent_Phone
    , Listing_Agent_Email
    , Office_Name
    , Office_Address
    , Office_Phone
    , Office_Email
    , Update_Timestamp
from 
(
   select Agent_SK
        , Listing_Agent_License_Number
        , Listing_Agent_Name
        , Listing_Agent_Address
        , Listing_Agent_Phone
        , Listing_Agent_Email
        , Office_Name
        , Office_Address
        , Office_Phone
        , Office_Email
        , Update_Timestamp
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Listing_Agent_Name, 
                                          Listing_Agent_Phone,  
                                          Listing_Agent_Address, 
                                          Listing_Agent_Email
                             ORDER BY Update_Timestamp DESC) AS rn
   from MLS
   where Agent_SK is not null
) AS t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks much.  I think my brain took a sick day without telling me.  Great answer.